# how to fetch images with same imageid in joined table

Tags: php

guys im using loop to fetch images of one user but they are displaying as many users

```
$fetchproduct="select  * from product inner join product_detail on product.id=product_detail.product_id join customer_detail on product.id=customer_detail.product_id join product_images on product.id=product_images.product_id where type='cyarabuze'";
                    $fetchresult=$db->query($fetchproduct);
                    while ($row = $fetchresult->fetch_assoc())
```

i also tried this

```
select DISTINCT images.product_images as images
```

in my image column in table uploaded by one user are having same img_id from product table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
DISTINCT product_images.id, 
product_images.image
/* add other columns you might need */
from product 
inner join product_detail on product.id=product_detail.product_id 
join customer_detail on product.id=customer_detail.product_id 
join product_images on product.id=product_images.product_id 
where 
type='cyarabuze
```